# Pass data from RecyclerView to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have referred few links regarding this topic but I still couldn't understand how to pass data from a `RecyclerView` to a `Fragment`[opening a Fragment on `Cardview` click]. Following is my `RecyclerView` class:

```
public class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoAdapter.PhotosHolder>
{
static class PhotosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    CardView cv;
    ImageView photo_img;

    PhotosHolder(final View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_photo);
        photo_img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thum_photo);        
    }
}

private List<PhotoInitialise> photo;
private Activity mContext;

public PhotoAdapter(List<PhotoInitialise> photos, Context mContext)
{
    this.photo=photos;
    this.mContext= (Activity) mContext;
}
@Override
public PhotosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.phototab_layout,parent,false);
    return new PhotosHolder(layoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PhotosHolder holder, final int position)
{       

    holder.photo_count.setText(photo.get(position).gettotalImages());
    holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {                
             // want to pass the value to a Fragment here and invoke the Fragment
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return photo.size();
}
}
```

This is the XML Layout of the Fragment that should be displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/photo_detail_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/photodetail_description"        
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

I already have an idea of how to pass the value to fragment but I never could able to invoke the layout. Now what should I write in my `onClick()` to initiate the Fragment Layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement interface to handle the click in the specified Fragment.
Sample code structure will be like below. You can customize and use it according to your need:

```
public InterfaceListItemClickListener{
    void listItemClickAction(<parameters to pass>);
}
```

In your fragment class implement this interface:

```
public class SampleFragment extends BaseFrgment implements InterfaceListItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void listItemClickAction(<parameters to pass>) {
        //override the interface function    
        //handle your click action here
    }

    //pass the instance of your interface to your adapter like below line
    YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(otherParameters, this);
}
```

In constructor of your Adapter access the interface:

```
public YourAdapter(otherParameters, InterfaceListItemClickListener clickListenerInferface ){
    //other assignations
    this.clickListenerInferface = clickListenerInferface;
}
```

and then onClick callback you can call your onclick function:

```
clickListenerInferface.listItemClickAction(<parameter to pass>);
```

Comment: I just want to know how to invoke fragment from recyclerview class. [invoke fragment on cardview click]